# What does "DIRECT" in a PAC file signifies

Tags: networking, curl, proxy, openssl, port

I have a PAC file that I need to parse to apply a proxy to the network.

The content of the pac file is:

```
function FindProxyForURL(url,host) { 
        return "DIRECT";
}
```

I want to know what `"DIRECT"` means here? How can I get the IP address of the proxy that's being used?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Direct means no proxy, so if it is really the content of the correct PAC file, there is no HTTP proxy on this network.

Answer (score 1):

'Direct' will send traffic to within the network, such as what you would want for a Intranet URL, or permanent VPN connection to a client, or a Sharepoint URL, are some examples. It will not go to the Proxy. To somewhere else on your network that your switches know what to do with.

In the file should be an entry like this:
return “PROXY proxy1:8080; PROXY proxy2:8080; DIRECT”;

proxy1 and proxy2 will be the IPs of the first and secondary Proxies in use.